# Autofill a column with month name depending on the date in another column - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new in working with Excel VBA and I have this problem.

I would like my userform to autofill dynamic range in a column based on the date picked by the user. When the "create" button is clicked, simultaneously, on one column of the sheet the date is populated and on another column beside it, the Month name is also populated depending on the date encoded. Do you think it'll be possible? Your efforts will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Week <> "" Then
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim LR1 As Long
        Dim LR3 As Long
        Dim LR4 As Long

        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

        ' get the last row from columns that has a value
        LR1 = ws.range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LR3 = ws.range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        LR4 = ws.range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        ' use the last row to determine how far down to extend the formula
        ws.range("D" & LR4 & ":D" & LR1).Value = Me.Week.Value
        ws.range("C" & LR3 & ":C" & LR1).Value = Me.DTPicker1.Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Please fill all fields!"
    End If
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

[image: Create Template GUI]

Comment: Please share your code/workaround so that we can take a look at your attempt.

Comment: Hi @PirateX Thank you so much for your interest. please see my updated post above with my codes provided.

Comment: What is `Me.Week` in your code? It is not described in your question. Also it seems that you output it next to the date value in the sheet, which is where you ask to put the month. Can you please be more precise in what you expect? A screenshot of both the form and another one with the desired output in your Excel sheet would maybe help.

Comment: Again, than you so much @trincot for your great concern, it is highly appreciated. I have already attached the screenshot of the form and the worksheet database above. So what's currently happening in the system is that when the create button is clicked, the week and the date value on the userform will be populated on columns C and D in the worksheet with the same length of cells with the column A. Meanwhile, I would like the column B to automatically populate the Month name which corresponds to the date column next to it when the create button is also clicked. Sorry for the inconvenience.Tnx

Comment: Does the Week value have anything to do with the Month? It seems to me that it is not related to your question. Can you confirm?

Comment: Is the question *only* to fill in the Month, or is there any issue with the other columns C, and D as well? Can you please make clear in your question what you actually need? Because as your question starts *"I would like my userform to autofill"* it looks like you don't have the autofill yet, but then in your code, it seems you already have it... I am confused.

Comment: I'm sorry for confusing you @trincot I don't how to thank you enough for attending all my concerns though my thoughts are confusing. Ahmm, the autofill for C and D columns are already settled, the only thing that needs to be accomplished is to only fill in the Month (Column B). I wanted the column B contents to be dependent on the dates shown in the column C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the month name in column B, add this to your code:

```
    Dim LR2 As Long
    ' ... 
    LR2 = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ' ...
    ws.Range("B" & LR2 & ":B" & LR1).FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(R[0]C[1], ""mmm"")"
```

This will actually insert a formula in the B column that represents the month name of the cell next to it.

Comment: Hi there @trincot! Thank you so much for showing you interest on my concern. Please see my updated post above with codes provided.

Comment: That worked like a magic. Thank you sooooooooooo much @trincot I can't find the right words to express my gratitude to you. God bless you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the Situation correctly, but maybe you can fill the second column just with ".formula = application.worksheetfunction("=month(...)")

Comment: Hi @Helge Thank you so much for your interest. please see my updated post above with my codes provided.